# How to show different ARR friendly error pages on timeout depending on downstream server

Tags: iis-7.5, custom-error-pages, custom-errors, arr

I'm trying to work out how we can go about serving different error pages from within ARR when a timeout occurs (http 502.3).

Scenario is we could host X number of different brands and want to supply different error pages if their servers are down.

The out of the box approach on a 502 error is that it will get the "Default Web Site" error pages, what I'm wondering is way we can provide that functionality without adding a new ARR server every time we bring on a new customer.

Any help you could give would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our final solution was deceptively simple. ARR doesn't have this functionality and e need code to allow logic, so we added a .aspx page with the appropriate host to error code mapping. Effectively a dictionary mapping within the .aspx page.